# 2 way TLS (1.2) between Java client and Apple pay server

Tags: java-8, tomcat7, tls1.2, applepay, applepayjs

Trying to achieve:
As required in Apple Pay for Web, 2 way TLS 1.2 is required. In my case i'm trying to hit apple pay server from my java  with json payload (which you can say as client).
https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs/applepaysession#2166532

My points of Concern:

1) Any command that list all the cipher suites supported? running on java 1.8.

2) What is required while making HttpsURLconnection.openconnection to be TLS1.2?

3) Any example code by which i can achieve this connection.

4) What are the settings required like certificate and private key?

Any help would be useful. 
I know i have asked very direct questions, but i will keep adding more specific questions in this.

**Update: First 3 points are done.
Now only Regarding point 4**: I'm sending both the files key and cert by converting to cert.p12 file and saving as new keystore.

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in merchant_id.cer -out merchant_id.pem
openssl pkcs12 -nodes -export -in merchant_id.pem -inkey clientprivate.key -out cert.p12 -name "Certificate"
```

After that running java code with VM arguments in eclipse:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=cert.p12 -Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

I can see following error in console:

```
*ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
* Certificate chain

** ECDHClientKeyExchange
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data: 
*
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 64
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 48
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the java code:

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();  
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(jsonInString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Failing at

```
conn.getOutputStream();
```

Using java 1.8

Comment: can you please! post code for first 3 points, am strugling with failed handshake, on create session, am trying with resttemplate and i pass factory ssl 1.2 and tried 3, i imported the cert into my jks localhost, and trying with ngrok to make my app public to test. and verify domain

Answer (score 1):

General answers in the order asked..

1. I found this very helpful to list all ciphers: https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html
2. I used this `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");` to set it to TLS 1.2.
3. I can't post my whole project here its too much code... It's a basic http request with all required fields sent along.
4. First create an "apple pay merchant id" certificate on apple's website, download it, extract the certificate and the key from it into 2 separate files, send both along with your request (with the password, of course).

Comment: Thanks yyf.The above 3 pointsare resolved.But i'm badly stuck in point 4. I'm sending both key and certificate by adding in keystore. But after ServerHello, i got the following error:WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake,length = 64
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 48
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()

Comment: I also struggled a lot until I got it to work... I downloaded the cert from apple and extracted **from it** a cert `openssl pkcs12 -nodes --nokeys -in merchant_id.pem -inkey clientprivate.key -out cert.p12` and a key `openssl pkcs12 -nodes --nocerts -in merchant_id.pem -inkey clientprivate.key -out key.p12` and then set both as the keystore for the request.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what is the difference. So, lets say you get merchant_id.cer from apple. Then you must have created csr and private key before that. After that from .cer file you have converted to merchant_id.pem also. Following that as you mentioned created cert and key.     Then how you have set both as keystore?? Can you share that step as well.

Comment: It would be great if you list the steps you have followed. I'm still struggling to make it work. Thanks yyf.

Comment: Uploading the CSR file in the Apple Developer Portal will generate a certificate file (merchant_id.cer) for you to download. This acts as the public key for your Merchant Identify Certificate. The private key is the CSR you provided to generate that certificate. In order to create a valid TLS connection to the Apple Pay merchant validation server, you will need to create a public-private key pair using the CSR and the CER files, such as using a tool like OpenSSL to create a .p12 file.